# Can a mercury thermometer be curve? Is there any reason they cant be curved?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, measurements

Is it compulsory for a mercury thermometer to be straight?

Comment: why not, but it would break more easily.and its more difficult to make the right scale readable.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is all about expansion of the mercury and hence the path can have any shape. [Here is a link](http://phisick.com/item/curved-clinical-thermometer-with-silver-mount/) to a curved thermometer for putting under the tongue.

> In a BMJ article on the 18th May 1912 the inventor lists the advantages of this instrument over straight thermometers. These are that is easily placed sublingually, that the thermometer obtains a more accurate reading being fully submerged, that it is easier to shake the mercury down and that the shape avoids damage from teeth. Whatever the claims it did not find common use and these thermometers are few and far between.